# Optimizar y reducir el número de conexiones a la base de datos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mvc, pdo

Estoy haciendo un proyecto bastante extenso donde sigo un modelo con PDO y MVC donde en algunas de las páginas que cargan superamos las 25 conexiones a la base de datos y por lo tanto da problemas de conexión con el servidor actual que tenemos ya que tiene fijado ese límite de conexiones y me gustaría saber si alguna posibilidad de reducir las consultas las conexiones actuales ya que sino tendremos que cambiar a un servidor dedicado.

Por ejemplo utilizando este módulo en concreto para categorías que cargan en el menú salen 5 conexiones.

cabezote.php

```
<!--=====================================
CATEGORÍAS
======================================-->

        <div class="col-xs-12 backColor" id="categorias">

            <?php

                $item = null;
                $valor = null;

                $categorias = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarCategorias($item, $valor);

                foreach ($categorias as $key => $value) {

                    echo '<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">

                            <h4>
                                <a href="'.$url.$value["ruta"].'" class="pixelCategorias">'.$value["categoria"].'</a>
                            </h4>

                            <hr>

                            <ul>';

                            $item = "id_categoria";

                            $valor = $value["id"];

                            $subcategorias = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarSubCategorias($item, $valor);

                            foreach ($subcategorias as $key => $value) {

                                    echo '<li><a href="'.$url.$value["ruta"].'" class="pixelSubCategorias">'.$value["subcategoria"].'</a></li>';
                                }   

                            echo '</ul>

                        </div>';
                }

            ?>  

        </div>

    </div>
```

productos-controlador.php

```
<?php

class ControladorProductos{

    /*=============================================
    MOSTRAR CATEGORÍAS
    =============================================*/

    static public function ctrMostrarCategorias($item, $valor){

        $tabla = "categorias";

        $respuesta = ModeloProductos::mdlMostrarCategorias($tabla, $item, $valor);

        return $respuesta;

    }

    /*=============================================
    MOSTRAR SUBCATEGORÍAS
    =============================================*/

    static public function ctrMostrarSubCategorias($item, $valor){

        $tabla = "subcategorias";

        $respuesta = ModeloProductos::mdlMostrarSubCategorias($tabla, $item, $valor);

        return $respuesta;

    }

?>
```

modelo-productos.php

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";

class ModeloProductos{

    /*=============================================
    MOSTRAR CATEGORÍAS
    =============================================*/

    static public function mdlMostrarCategorias($tabla, $item, $valor){

        if($item != null){

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");

            $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetch();

        }else{

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        }

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;

    }

    /*=============================================
    MOSTRAR SUB-CATEGORÍAS
    =============================================*/

    static public function mdlMostrarSubCategorias($tabla, $item, $valor){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;

    }
?>
```

¿Es posible reducir esta consulta de categorias en el cabezote.php para por ejemplo intentar tener 1 sola conexión o 2 máximo?

En general, ¿hay algún modo global de recudir todas estas conexiones o hacerlo de otra manera? Ya que como comento anteriormente al llevar esta parte a un proyecto mucho más extenso superamos las 25 y hasta 30 conexiones en algunas zonas de la web.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que necesitas es aplicar el patrón singleton en tu objeto conexión para mantener una sola instancia de la conexión y obtenerla cada vez que la necesites.

En vez de crear constantemente una nueva conexión con la función conectar() tendrás una función que se llame getInstance(), dicha función verificará si ya existe una conexión creada y si no existe la crea y la retorna en caso contrario simplemente retorna la conexión existente.

Te dejo una implementación de la clase conexión siguiendo este patrón.

[conexión pdo](https://gist.github.com/ftonato/2973a55baf8eef6795a48804dcdb71dd)

Explicando un poco el código del enlace:

```php
class DB {
    protected static $instance;
    protected function __construct() {}
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(empty(self::$instance)) {
            $db_info = array(
                "db_host" => "localhost",
                "db_port" => "3306",
                "db_user" => "user",
                "db_pass" => "pass",
                "db_name" => "ftonato",
                "db_charset" => "UTF-8");
            try {
                self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db_info['db_host'].';port='.$db_info['db_port'].';dbname='.$db_info['db_name'], $db_info['db_user'], $db_info['db_pass']);
                self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);  
                self::$instance->query('SET NAMES utf8');
                self::$instance->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
            } catch(PDOException $error) {
                echo $error->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Lo principal es que tienes una variable protected y static llamada instance que almacenará la conexión, la función getInstance() (que también puede llamarse por ejemplo getConnection()) retorna lo que está almacenado en la variable instance (que es la conexión) siempre y cuando no se encuentre vacía dicha variable, si está vacía primero se crea la conexión antes de retornar la variable instance, el tema acá es que como dicha variable es statica se mentendrá la misma conexión o instancia de la conexión luego de crearse la primera vez, de esa manera así llames a la función getInstance() varias veces siempre vas a obtener la misma conexión o instancia.

Ya luego está un ejemplo de como usarla, simplemente es obtener la instancia de la conexión y preparar el statement:

```php
$db = DB::getInstance();
$sqlExample = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE _id = 1';
$stm = $db->prepare($sqlExample);
$stm->execute();
```

Añadiendo la sugerencia de Bryro, si quieres optimizar el tiempo de consulta a la base de datos puedes almacenar con memcached el resultado de las mismas, memcached es un programa que guarda (crea un caché) en memoria (la RAM de la máquina) datos u objetos. Hace que sean más rápidas las consultas ya que ir a la base de datos es más lento que ir a la memoria RAM debido que acceder a la base de datos es leer en el disco duro o unidad SSD los datos (lo cual puede ser algo lento dependiendo del disco o unidad) mientras que la RAM (rapid access memory) está diseñada para que los tiempos de acceso a la misma sean muy rápidos.

Entonces la idea es que antes de ejecutar una consulta en la base de datos primero veas si la tienes almacenada en la caché (o la RAM si se puede decir) de una ejecución anterior, si es así se retorna desde la caché y en caso contrario se accede a la base de datos, se guarda en la caché para posteriores consultas y se retorna el resultado. Usando parte de tu código para ilustrar el concepto sería algo como:

```php
if($item != null){

  //creación del objeto memcached
  $memcached = new Memcached();
  $memcached->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);

  //intentando acceder al objeto guardado en la cache por la clave $item
  //suponiendo que $item es una cadena de texto
  $response = $memcached->get($item);

  //si estaba guardado en la cache se retorna
  if ($response) {
    return $response;
  }
  else{
    //si no esta almacenado en la cache se accede a la base de datos
    $stmt = Conexion::getInstance()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");

    $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt -> execute();

    $result= $stmt->fetch()

    //se guarda en memoria el resultado de la consulta con la clave $item
    $memcached->set($item,$result);

    return $result;
  }

}
```

Cabe acotar que para utilizar memcached hay que instalarlo primero y configurarlo como una extensión de php.

Comment: te dare +1 y adicional podrias incluir a tu respuesta el uso de `memcached`! saludos!

Comment: Agregada la sugerencia, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Por ahora solo he probado la primera parte del ejemplo (me falta probar el método objeto memcached) y a la vez he probado otra recomendación, así que explico lo que estoy haciendo ya que a la vez tengo nueva dudas.

Del ejemplo 1 por ejemplo aquí he realizado estos cambios:

en conexion.php

```
class DB {

    protected static $instance;
    protected function __construct() {}
    public static function getInstance() {  
        if(empty(self::$instance)) {
            $db_info = array(
                "db_host" => "localhost",
                "db_port" => "",
                "db_user" => "root",
                "db_pass" => "",
                "db_name" => "nombrebd",
                "db_charset" => "UTF-8");
            try {
                self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db_info['db_host'].';port='.$db_info['db_port'].';dbname='.$db_info['db_name'], $db_info['db_user'], $db_info['db_pass']);
                self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);  
                self::$instance->query('SET NAMES utf8');
                self::$instance->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');               
            } catch(PDOException $error) {
                echo $error->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    public static function setCharsetEncoding() {
        if (self::$instance == null) {
            self::connect();            
        }
        self::$instance->exec(
            "SET NAMES 'utf8';
            SET character_set_connection=utf8;
            SET character_set_client=utf8;
            SET character_set_results=utf8");

    }
}
```

Y luego en el modelo hice este cambio:

productos-modelo.php

```
/*=============================================
    MOSTRAR SUB-CATEGORÍAS SINGLETON (opción DB)
    =============================================*/

    static public function mdlMostrarSubCategorias($tabla, $item, $valor){              

        $stmt = DB::getInstance()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");        
        DB::setCharsetEncoding();       
        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);              
        $stmt -> execute();
        return $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt -> close();
        $stmt = null;   

    }
```

Hasta aquí me reduce por ejemplo la conexión de 5 a 1, y si luego lo aplico en categorías o cualquier otra zona de la web sigue reduciendo dicha conexión.

También he probado otra opción que me han recomendado que era extender mi clase anterior Conexion y crear una nueva para instanciar con singleton de esta manera:

conexion.php

```
class Conexion{

    public function conectar(){

        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nombrebd",
                        "root",
                        "",
                        array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                              PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
                        );

        if ($link) {            
                    echo "Acabo de conectarme desde Conexion";
                }       

        return $link;

    }

}

// Facilita el manejo extendiendo de PDO
class DBmysql extends PDO {
    // Crea solo una instancia de la clase (patrón Singleton)
    private static $_instance = false;

    public static function conectar() {
        // Verificar si no se ha realizado la conexión
        if(self::$_instance === false) {
            // Conectamos a la base de datos
            try {
                // Verifico que los parámetros son correctos.
                self::$_instance = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nombrebd",
                        "root",
                        "",
                        array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                              PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
                        );

                //Intento ver en el código fuente las actuales conexiones a la BD.
                echo "Acabo de conectarme a la BD";

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                // Hay que elaborar mejor el manejo de errores, esto solo es ejemplo
                die('No se puede establecer una conexión a base de datos.');
            }
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

Luego por ejemplo en el modelo de subcategorías solo cambio Conexion por DBmysql y listo:

```
/*=======================================================
MOSTRAR SUB-CATEGORÍAS SINGLETON (Opción clase extendida)
=========================================================*/

    static public function mdlMostrarSubCategorias($tabla, $item, $valor){

        $stmt = DBmysql::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetchAll();     

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;

    }
```

Por lo que veo ahora al aplicar este nuevo método reduce en gran cantidad el número de conexiones a la base de datos, pero no estoy seguro del todo si lo estoy haciendo de la manera correcta tanto en ver cuantas conexiones hago por página y también en como lo estoy aplicando al código actual.

Por otro lado también tengo la duda si es aconsejable aplicar este método en toda la web y consultas para así tener solo 1 conexión por página o es mejor simplemente aplicarlo en zonas o consultas más extensas como pueden ser categorías, listar productos etc etc.

Por ejemplo aquí también lo he probado:

```
/*=============================================
    MOSTRAR CATEGORÍAS
    =============================================*/

    static public function mdlMostrarCategorias($tabla, $item, $valor){

        if($item != null){          

            $stmt =  DBmysql::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");           

            $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetch();        


        }else{            

            $stmt =  DBmysql::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();        

        }

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;

    }
```

¿Es aconsejable entonces cambiarlo en toda la web a la nueva conexión **$stmt = DBmysql::** o debo de seguir dejando según que zonas el modo anterior como por ejemplo categorías  **$stmt = Conexion::**?

Gracias por vuestra ayuda, saludos.

PD: Se me olvidaba comentar otra recomendación que aun no he probado: [PDOStatement::closeCursorphp](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.closecursor)